# Need help solving cylindrical Laplacian

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve the cylindrical Laplacian for a heated disk in a large cylinder. The cylinder and disk have constant temperatures and I only care about the temperature field between the disk and the cylinder. For some reason the result is not the smooth temperature transition I'd expect. What's wrong with my code?

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ThinDisk[R_] := (
  With[{inner = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.001}}, R], 
    outer = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]}, (mesh = 
     ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[outer, inner], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001])];
  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[T[r, \[Phi], z], {r, \[Phi], z}, 
      "Cylindrical"] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[T[r, \[Phi], z] == 300, 
     r > 0.5 || Abs[z] > 0.5], 
    DirichletCondition[T[r, \[Phi], z] == 400, 
     r < 0.5 && Abs[z] < 0.5]}, T, {r, \[Phi], z} \[Element] mesh])
```

Run the code for a disk with radius 0.1 and plot.

```
sol = ThinDisk[0.1]
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 sol[r, \[Phi], z], "CenterPlanes", {r, \[Phi], z} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

v13.3 MacOSx

Comment: The documentation has a section on solving the heat transfer equation in cylindrical coordinates [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#979556736). But you can also use "RegionSymmetry"->"Axysymmetric" for which you find examples on the [HeatTransferPDEComponent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html) ref page.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit where you want the boundary conditions?

Comment: Also, for the FEM solver you will need to specify PDE in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation! I want boundary conditions of T = 300 on the outer cylinder and T = 400 on the disk. To your most recent comment, does that mean I can't use the cylindrical Laplacian when using FEM solver? I'm not sure whether the from-scratch approach I'm taking above is better than using the predefined HeatTransfer functions for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use Cartesian coordinated (or use a RegionSymmetry). Something like this should get you started:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ThinDisk[
  R_] := (With[{inner = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.001}}, R], 
    outer = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]}, (mesh = 
     ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[outer, inner], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1])];
  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[T[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[T[x, y, z] == 300, 
     x^2 + y^2 > 0.5 && Abs[z] > 0.5], 
    DirichletCondition[T[x, y, z] == 400, 
     x^2 + y^2 < 0.5 && Abs[z] < 0.5]}, 
   T, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh])
sol = ThinDisk[0.1];
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 sol[x, y, z], "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

Have a look at the RegionSymmetry option for the `HeatTransportPDEComponent`. That should be useful in your case.

What also may be useful for you is the section on ElementMarker in ElementMesh Generation tutorial. That allows for easy access to positions where `DirichletConditions` can be set - you are looking for PointElement markers.